# Removing web page link - Cruisecontrol.net Email Publisher

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am working on continuous Integration using CCNet. I am using Email
publisher for publishing build results. CCNet sends email in following
format:

CruiseControl.NET Build Results for project In4SuiteRE_DEV_Build (web page)

---

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Project:  In4SuiteRE_DEV_Build

Date of build:  2010-10-25 19:00:24

Running time:  00:00:09

Integration Request:  Build (ForceBuild) triggered from REMAINT

However, i want to remove the first line inside body that is "

CruiseControl.NET Build Results for project In4SuiteRE_DEV_Build (web page)
" from email. Why is that, I do not want developers to access that CCNet
page. Because if they access then they can force build which i do not want
them to do.

Kindly let me know if you know the answer.

Chandan

Answer (score 0):

With CruiseControl.Net version 1.5, you can set permissions on who can Force a build.  Then it doesn't matter that they have the web page - the Force button should be disabled